# Adding elements from JTextField to ArrayList

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jtextfield, jtextarea

so I have an assignment that include GUI that contain:

- `JTextField` that lets user enter an input into the text field
- `AddButton` adds the input into an ArrayList
- `ListButton` displays the content of ArrayList in the `JTextArea`

**The problem is:** When I enter [1,2,3] the output only show me the last element [3], how to fix this?

```
public class Example extends JFrame {
    private final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 300;
    private final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 300;
    private JPanel panel1, panel2;
    private JLabel messageLabel;
    private JTextField input;
    private JTextArea output;
    private JButton addButton, listButton;
    String userInput;
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

public Example() {
    setTitle("Array Exercise");
    setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,1));

    messageLabel = new JLabel("Input");
    input = new JTextField(5);
    addButton = new JButton("Add");
    listButton = new JButton("List");

    panel1.add(messageLabel);
    panel1.add(input);
    panel1.add(addButton);
    panel1.add(listButton);
    add (panel1, BorderLayout.WEST);

    output = new JTextArea(12, 10);
    panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.add(output);
    add(panel2, BorderLayout.EAST);


    setVisible(true);
    input.requestFocus();

    ButtonListener bh =  new ButtonListener();

    addButton.addActionListener(bh);
    listButton.addActionListener(bh);      
}   
private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener {     
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        userInput = input.getText();

        if (e.getSource() == addButton) {
            list.add(userInput);
            output.setText(userInput + " added.");
            input.setText("");
            input.requestFocus();
        }

        else if (e.getSource() == listButton) {                
            list.stream().forEach(x-> output.setText(x));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should break your question down in to multiple parts. The first you want to understand how to get text from a GUI element. Then you want to parse the text to create an array, Last you want to return the last element only as an array. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4):

The JTextField its text to a new text *for each* element in your list. What you have to do is something like this instead:

```
for(String s : list){
    outPut.append(s + "\n");
} 
//Use "\n" if you want each string on a new line. Otherwise, skip it
```

(I used this type of for-loop for clarity)

Now it "adds" (appends) each new String in your list. In your code, it sets the text to the first String. The sets the text to the second String (and so on). So remember to clear the area with perhaps ***setText("");*** every time you want to print out, for example, a new list of Strings.

Answer (score 1):

complementing Oskar's answer:

`setTest()` sets the whole text of the text area, overwriting the previous content. So the last value set is the (only) one that will be saved at the end.

Since already using Streams, you could use:

```
output.setText(list.stream().collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```